# getting a certain number of characters from a 2D char array

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a 2D char array and I want to print the first three characters of every five characters in each nested array. This is what I am doing:

```
char [][] one ={ {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','3'},{'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','7'},{'q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','2'}};

int aSize=5;
char [] firstThree=new char[3];
for (int i=0; i< one.length;i++){
    for (int j=0; j< aSize;j++){
        for(int m=0; m<3;m++){
            firstThree[m]=one[i][m];
        }
    }

    System.out.print(firstThree);
    System.out.println(""); 
}
```

this gives the following output:

```
abc
ijk
qrs
```

I want the output:

```
abc
fgh
ijk
nop
qrs
vwx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work to do it dynamically, so it would work for even longer input lengths.

Note that the third nested loop is not necessary, and you just need to iterate fully through each nested array, using a `count` variable to keep track of where you are in regards to adding the first three of each five characters.

Note that I also used an `ArrayList<String>`, to keep track of the three-character sequences that should be printed, but that's not really necessary, you could just print directly in the `(count == 3)` case.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrintThreeOfFive
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     char [][] one ={ {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','3'},{'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','7'},{'q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','2'}};

     int aSize=5;
     ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
     char [] firstThree=new char[3];
     for (int i=0; i< one.length;i++){
         int count = 0;
         for (int j=0; j < one[i].length; j++){

           //re-set count at the 5th character
           if (count == 4){ 
             count = 0;
             continue; //continue so that the fifth character is not added
           }

           //if in first three of five, add it to firstThree
           if (count < 3){
             firstThree[count]=one[i][j];
           }

           //increment count, and add to the list if at the third character
           count++;
           if (count == 3){
             output.add(new String(firstThree));
           }

         }
     }

    for (String s : output){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
abc
fgh
ijk
nop
qrs
vwx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
for (int j=5; j < 8;j++){
    firstThree[j-5]=one[i][j];
}
```

You don't need 3 loops to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You can create another array to read after 5 index like:

```
 for(int m=0; m<3;m++){
     firstThree[m]=one[i][m];
     nextThree[m]=one[i+5][m];
 }
```

Comment: This gave me an index out of bounds exception. I understand what you are saying but is there a way to dynamically code this? So, if I have unknown number of chars in an array and I want to get the first 3 from every 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Masud is close but his solution has some runtime error.Change your index a bit to solve this.

```
  for(int m=0; m<3;m++){
     firstThree[m]=one[i][m];
     nextThree[m]=one[i][m+5];
 }
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/KZjKZ7)